# Nested data/children with Angular's factory $resource

Tags: angularjs, recursion, nested, angularjs-resource, angularjs-factory

I have a server side API method which returns an array of locations in JSON and have created a resource in Angular to retrieve the entire array of locations upon loading.

All locations also have infinite nested/children locations which is contained within an array inside of the 'children' property for each location. Here's an example to demonstrate what the server response may look like:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Top Level',
        children:
        [
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Second Level',
                children: [ ... ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The $save() method works correctly when calling it on top level nodes, as expected (although the payload also includes the nested children property when executing the POST).

This however does not work when attempting to call $save() on any of the nested 'children' nodes. This leads me to the conclusion that the resource methods are not attached in a recursive manner; but is there a way in which one may specify a recursive or nested property in a resource (I've found nothing in the official angular documentation along these lines) so that I may attach the $save() method to nested children nodes as well?

Here's my existing code for reference:

```
angular.module('locations', [ 'ngResource' ])
    .factory('Locations', function( $resource )
    {
        return $resource(
            './locations', {},
            { query:  { method: 'GET', isArray: true } }
        );
    });
```

Comment: A temporary workaround which worked for me was to instantiate a new instance of my Locations factory/resource on any 'children' items, allowing me to call .$save() on the items. I also implemented the transformRequest callBack inside of the $resource's method properties to exclude the 'children' items when saving, as well as various other properties which were not necessary for the update (POST).